# RobotFramework: How to catch ambiguous error in Run Keyword And Expect Error

Tags: robotframework

I use robot framework at following environment.

- Python 2.7.6
- robotframework 2.8.7
- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

I test REST API, with keyword like this.

```
MyKeyword  
Send Request -> Check Response Status Code -> Return Response content
```

And I use this keyword in negative case like followings.

```
Run Keyword And Expect Error    400 != 201    MyKeyword    @args
```

In this case, if status code is 401, robot fails with this messages.

```
Expected error '400 != 201' but got '401 != 201'.
```

But I want to check that request will be rejected because of client reason,
so I wish status code were **40X**.

How can I set Run Keyword And Expect Error ambiguous expected message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make use of wildcard characters as per the documentation - http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Expect%20Error

I've never used it before but what I think you need change it to this:

```
Run Keyword And Expect Error    40? != 201    MyKeyword    @args
```

Perhaps I've misunderstood the docs as I've never used this before though, in which case I would probably look to catch all errors:

Run Keyword And Expect Error    *    MyKeyword    @args

It looks a little strange to me what you're doing though, should you not be using the variable the response result is returned in and checking against that?  i.e. ${response} != 40?

Comment: I'm sorry for late. I misssed the description of pattern.. Thank you very much. in my case, this keyword only return ${response.content}, and this is shared and if I change that affect others. So I want to use existing keyword with positive and negative case for readablilty.Thanks.